# Set value to select (Angular)

Tags: angular, select

I have a select tab and want to set value to it in `ngOnInit()`. 
My select looks like:

```
<div class="form__field">
  <label class="form__label">Project</label>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select formControlName="project">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let project of projects" [value]="project">
        {{project.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Where project is on object with fields like

```
{
author: 'name', 
name: 'name',
participants: {'', ''},
uid: '',
projectId:''
}
```

I set a value in .ts file but it doesn't work. (It works for other fields but not for this select) I've tried different ways like `this.task.projectFull.name...`

```
this.form.setValue({
   name: this.task.name,
   priority: this.task.priority,
   assignee: this.task.assignee,
   project: this.task.projectFull, //projectFull: this.form.value.project
});
```

`this.task` its my task which I get from firestore, its interface looks like:

```
 export default interface Task {
  id?: string;
  name?: string;
  createdBy?: string;
  completed?: boolean;
  priority?: string;
  assignee?: string;
  projectFull?;
  project?: string;
  projectId?: string;
}
```

Would be really grateful for any help!

Comment: edit: it seems possible

Comment: oh, got it, but is there any way so I can put a value to it? 
Its a component to edit task where I need to get all data which are in firestore and after editing need to update this values. And I use this object in other functions, so I can't replace it to string but need to show it in select

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a `compareWith` function as described here: [Customizing option selection](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection)

```html
<mat-select [compareWith]="compareFn" formControlName="project">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let project of projects" [value]="project">
      {{project.name}}
   </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

```js
compareFn(p1: Project, p2: Project): boolean {
    return p1 && p2 ? p1.projectId === p2.projectId : p1 === p2;
}
```